# Can I move the default domain Administrator account to a new OU without breaking something?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Question really asks it all.  I want to apply a GP to the Domain Administrator account, but when I go to GPMC, you don't see the default OUs like Computers or Users listed.

Can I move the account to a new OU without breaking a system dependancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; this is safe (and, in fact, recommended) unless you have anything pointing to the account that uses the LDAP path (usually a third party application - Microsoft is pretty good about using the sid instead).

The reason these aren't visible in GPMC, by the way, is that they aren't technically OUs.